# Python statistics.median() returning "StatisticsError: no median for empty data" despite being given a list of 20 items

Tags: python, median

I am a 3rd year economics major who has recently picked up a minor in computer science. Suffice to say, I know very little about coding, but I am currently taking a data structures course and in the process of coding one of my assignments I ran into this issue:

```
def median_expense(transactions):
    """Return the median value of transaction amounts."""
    transvalues = []
    for item in transactions:
        transvalues.append(item[1])
    return statistics.median(transvalues)


def significant_transactions(transactions, n_trailing=10):
    """Return a list of significant transactions.

    A transaction is significant if the amount is greater than or equal to
    five times of the median spending for a trailing number of transactions
    """
    sigtrans = []
    trail = 0
    for item in transactions:
        if item in transactions[0:n_trailing-1]:
            pass
        else:
            print(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
            med = median_expense(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
            if item[1] >= 5 * med:
                sigtrans.append(item)
        trail += 1
    return sigtrans
```

transactions is a list consisting of a number of iterations of a named tuple "Transaction" which is defined as Transaction = namedtuple("Transaction", ["time", "amount", "company", "phone"]). These are pulled from a text file which is processed into the list transactions by another function.
It is called in a separate validator function with

```
def test_significant_transactions():
    """Testing significant_transactions"""
    module = import_file("fraud.py")
    transactions = module.load_transactions("transactions.txt")
    returned = module.late_night_transactions(transactions)
    Transaction = module.Transaction

    expected = [
        Transaction(
            time="2019-11-09 19:35:55",
            amount=181.75,
            company="White-Carr",
            phone="+1-683-988-9471x923",
        ),
        Transaction(
            time="2020-06-29 04:31:39",
            amount=47.73,
            company="Moore-Oliver",
            phone="+1-956-998-4999x4202",
        ),
        Transaction(
            time="2021-08-30 02:30:08",
            amount=150.32,
            company="Kiss Kiss Nyrt.",
            phone="+36 49 013-1271",
        ),
    ]

    returned = module.significant_transactions(transactions, 20)
    assert set(expected) == set(returned)
    assert len(module.significant_transactions(transactions, 5)) == 34
    assert len(module.significant_transactions(transactions, 10)) == 10
    assert len(module.significant_transactions(transactions, 15)) == 9
```

The issue I am running into is that within the significant_transactions function, the statistics.median() always returns a StatisticsError: no median for empty data. I have tried printing the list that I am passing into it just a single line beforehand and it prints a full list of 20 tuples. I do not understand what part of my code is causing this list to simply disappear before it is passed into statistics.median().

Some examples of tuples from the text document since there are several hundred in the original file:

> 2019-07-10 00:53:16 | $18.84 | Mccarty Inc | +1-656-321-9087
>
> 2019-07-10 10:45:35 | $53.19 | Miller, Tyler and Brennan |
> +1-133-495-8787x11296
>
> 2019-07-11 14:47:00 | $28.88 | Thomas-Ochoa | +1-127-502-6419
>
> 2019-07-12 00:06:10 | $5.43 | Gonzalez, Perry and Martinez |
> +1-207-627-7386x43758
>
> 2019-07-13 17:02:56 | $12.39 | Fazekas Márton Kht. | +36 24 197-2587
>
> 2019-07-14 22:11:02 | $1.51 | Marshall, Reed and Decker |
> +1-865-728-7544
>
> 2019-07-15 07:04:02 | $36.71 | Garcia-Ho | +1-213-595-4661x89568
>
> 2019-07-16 10:25:37 | $19.85 | Martin Inc | +1-370-678-8277x7188
>
> 2019-07-16 18:19:43 | $1.93 | Glass, Oconnor and Harris |
> +1-550-792-2702x310
>
> 2019-07-17 02:01:20 | $4.19 | Dalton-Robinson | +1-053-420-4309x78603
>
> 2019-07-18 05:23:29 | $59.89 | Stein Group | +1-097-265-7703

Comment: Could you include the list for `Transactions` and the call to your functions? It is difficult to assist without all the information which could be contributing to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem resides in the logic you have within the loop. I'm not certain of what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully my comment gives you an insight of what may be the problem:

This is your code:

```py
def significant_transactions(transactions, n_trailing=10):
    """Return a list of significant transactions.

    A transaction is significant if the amount is greater than or equal to
    five times of the median spending for a trailing number of transactions
    """
    sigtrans = []
    trail = 0
    for item in transactions:
        if item in transactions[0:n_trailing-1]:
            pass
        else:
            print(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
            med = median_expense(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
            if item[1] >= 5 * med:
                sigtrans.append(item)
        trail += 1
    return sigtrans
```

Now, in the first if `if item in transactions[0:n_trailing-1]`, you're doing nothing with the first `n_trailing` elements, right? Are you aware that `pass` is just "doing nothing"? For the first `n_trailing` elements, you're just incrementing `trail`. Is that what you want?

If you want to skip the loop (including the `trail += 1`) for the first `n_trailing` elements, then you want to use `continue`.

That part of your code is equivalent to this:

```py
trail = n_trailing
for item in transactions[n_trailing:]:
    print(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
    med = median_expense(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
    if item[1] >= 5 * med:
        sigtrans.append(item)
    trail += 1
```

Anyway, your error says `StatisticsError: no median for empty data`, which leads us to think that there's something wrong with the call to median_expense: `median_expense(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])`

I think the error is that, since `transactions` isn't too big, you can't get the items between `(trail - n_trailing)` and `trail - 1`, because there aren't any, so it tries to calculate the median for empty data.

In an array with 20 items, calling your code with `n_trailing = 5`, your code would:

1. Increment `trail` for the first 4 items, `trail = 4`.
2. print `transactions[(4 - 5): 4-1]` = `transactions[-1:3]` -> returns an empty list.
3. Crash on `median_expense` because the list passed in empty.

Again, I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but is this code close to what you want?

```py
def significant_transactions(transactions, n_trailing=10):
    """Return a list of significant transactions.

    A transaction is significant if the amount is greater than or equal to
    five times of the median spending for a trailing number of transactions
    """
    sigtrans = []
    trail = n_trailing
    for item in transactions[n_trailing:]:
        print(transactions[(trail - n_trailing):trail-1])
        med = median_expense(transactions[(trail-n_trailing):trail-1])
        if item[1] >= 5 * med:
            sigtrans.append(item)
        trail += 1
    return sigtrans
```